# Independent set on colour critical graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I want to prove the following property on graphs:

**For every independent set $S$ of a colour critical graph $G$, the equality $\chi(G-S) = \chi(G)-1$** holds.

I cannot even intuitively understand why this property is true. I mean, $S$ can have a lots of vertices from $G$, so I don't see why removing any $S$ with the single and only property that the nodes in it are not adjacent between themselves decrements the chromatic colour only by $1$ and not even more.

I would really appreciate any ideas and intuitive explanation of why this property holds given the hypothesis on the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: You really don't see why $\chi(G)\le\chi(G-S)+1$? It's not intuitive that adding a set of vertices with no edges between them can't increase the chromatic number by more than one? Why can't you just take a new colour and give the new colour to all the new vertices?

Comment: I’d assume the lack of intuition comes from the obscure statement of the problem, namely that the color critical property is important.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually prove a stronger result: If $S$ is an independent set of a graph $G$, then $\chi(G-S) \geq \chi(G)-1$.

As an additional hint, suppose that $\chi(G-S) < \chi(G)-1$.

> Could you use this to come up with a good coloring of $G$.